# Asyncio: Run future from another future without awaiting it

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, future

What am I trying to do:

1. Send an image to a server and receive task_id from it
2. Run another future that will check the status by task_id
3. Do it again

So the problem is: I want to run the future that will check task status in parallel from inside my main future

Right now I have this code:

```
async def post_async_recognize_timeout(in_url, filepath, outer_ids, timeout, exp_time, token, check_timeout):
    start_time = time()
    while time() - start_time <= exp_time:
        with filepath.open('rb') as file:
            in_files = {'image': file}
            async with ClientSession() as session:
                async with session.post(in_url, data=in_files) as response:
                    body = await response.json()
                    task_id = body['task_id']
                    future = asyncio.ensure_future(check_task_status(in_url, token, outer_ids, check_timeout, {'id': task_id, 'created_at': time()}))
                    # How should I run this future now ??
        await asyncio.sleep(timeout)

async def check_task_status(in_url, token, result, timeout, task):
    while True:
        async with ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(f"{in_url}{task['id']}?token={token}") as response:
                body = await response.json()
                if body['message'] != 'Async task not done':
                    task['status'] = 'Done' if body['message'] == None else f"ERROR: {body['message']}"
                    task['done_at'] = time()
                    result.append(task)
                    break
        await asyncio.sleep(timeout)
```

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what is the problem with the current code? It seems like it should do what you expect.

Comment: @user4815162342 the thing is, I am not awaiting the future I created anywhere in the code, so it would cause an error. And I am not really sure how I can await it here, because I need both tasks to work in parallel, so if I await `check_statuses` I'll stop the execution of the `post_async`

Comment: *I am not awaiting the future I created anywhere in the code, so it would cause an error.* - What error are you referring to? Asyncio allows creating a future to run in the background - for example, [this code](https://pastebin.com/hL6T4XFC) executes `foo` in parallel with `main()` and shows no warnings or errors for `foo` not getting awaited. *And I am not really sure how I can await it here* - you don't; please edit the question to elaborate how the code you have shown have is misbehaving.

Comment: @user4815162342 your code works because you're using asyncio.run, I am using asyncio.run_until_complete

Comment: Changing `asyncio.run(main())` to `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())` ([pastebin](https://pastebin.com/cTvpLNUR)) has no effect, the program still runs with no error or warning. Again, can you please edit the question to specify which error you are getting (or what problem in general)? Without that information, or a minimal example that reproduces the issue, your question is basically unanswerable because it's not clear what problem needs solving.